# SQL - Como fazer vários INSERTs numa tabela com o resultado de um SELECT * de outra tabela em uma query

Tags: sql, query, join

Olá, gostaria de saber como fazer vários INSERTs numa tabela com o resultado de um SELECT de todos os id de outra tabela tabela que não estão como chave estrangeira na primeira tabela.

Já tenho a query do SELECT com LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT id FROM exemplo ex LEFT JOIN outra out ON ex.id = out.exemplo_id where out.exemplo_id IS NULL
```

Isso retorna todos os n IDs da outra tabela que não estão na primeira, o que eu quero é fazer tipo uma estrutura de repetição que irá executar  INSERTs n vezes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não precisa disso, você pode simplesmente fazer o select logo apos o insert, fazendo com que ele seja o value, abaixo um exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

Basta que eles tenham os mesmos argumentos caso, não você pode escolher quais quer nos dois, assim:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

Assim o insert sera realizado automaticamente.

**EDIT**

Caso queira utilizar apenas um dos campos basta colocar os outros valores manualmente assim:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT 'Valor manual varchar', 5, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

Desta forma apenas a column trÊs será puxada da query e o restante será repido o texto inserido.

Comment: Eu queria usar o SELECT para apenas um campo da tabela, mas vou tentar fazer JOINs para conseguir todos os campos no resultado.

Comment: Você não precisa usar todos, vou editar somando esta informação

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou muito bem, não sabia que dava para dar um SELECT em apenas um texto :).

Comment: Da sim, obrigado por dar setinha para cima e marcar como certo. Precisando estamos ae.